# redirect error output to function in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How do I redirect the error output from a command to a function?

E.g. I have:

```
function logit(){
    read output
    echo "error occured -- $output" >> $file
}

mkdir /tmp/pop.txt | logit
```

But the above doesn't work, the variable "$output" doesn't contain anything.

Comment: You have to redirect stderr(2) to stdout(1) to make it work like this:
`mkdir /tmp/pop.txt 2>&1 | logit`

Comment: or shorter form : `mkdir /tmp/pop.txt |& logit`

Comment: And consider using `-p` option for `mkdir`.

Comment: It works, but now I have another issue, I have other commands following mkdir, like chown, and even though they don't trigger any errors, they still trigger the "logit" function.
Is there a way to trigger the command upon receiving stderr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you mean (in a comment), but perhaps you are looking for something like:

```
logit(){
    printf "error occured -- ";
    cat
} >> "$file"

exec 3>&1
{
    mkdir /tmp/pop.txt 
    chown ...
    chmod ... 
} 2>&1 1>&3  | logit
```

This routes the stdout of all the commands in the block to the original stdout of the script while directing the errors streams of all to the `logit` function.  Rather than simply dumping `error occurred --` as a header and ignoring newlines in the input, it might be better to implement `logit` as:

```
logit(){ sed 's/^/ERROR: /' >> "$file"; }
```

or maybe even add a timestamp:

```
logit(){ perl -ne 'printf "%s: ERROR: %s", scalar gmtime, $_'; } >> "$file"
```

Comment: ah, interesting, thanks.